# Are there any necessary conditions of the existence of a Hamiltonian cycle on directed graphs

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs, hamiltonian-graphs

I'm trying to prove that one concrete directed graph has no Hamiltonian cycle, but didn't seem to find any relevant theorems

Comment: A weak necessary condition is having no directed cuts. This is a set of vertices X such that all arcs with one end in X either all leave X or all enter X.

Comment: It's got to be connected... But the main relevant theorem is that testing for the existence of a Hamiltonian cycle is, in general, NP-complete; so unless P=NP it doesn't scale well.